# Building a constant hierarchy structure

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm having trouble coming up with an elegant solution to what I want. I have a series of items (say, hotels, flights, tours, etc.)

Each on of these items have min and max age values. I want to create a constant to hold all of these. I started doing the standard:

```
public static class AgeConstants
{
   public const int MinHotelAge = 0;
   public const int MaxHotelAge = 10;
   ......
}
```

But then I thought, "this seems a little clunky". It'd be much nicer if I accessed these constants as `AgeConstants.Hotel.Min`,  `AgeConstants.Hotel.Max`,  `AgeConstants.Flight.Min`, etc.

But I can't come up with a good way to implement this type of pattern. Does anyone know of a good pattern that will allow me to access constants in this fashion? Is this feasible?

I've tried a few but nothing that will add any benefit to this question.

Comment: Should these be constants in the first place? Perhaps instances of a class having readonly properties for `Min` and `Max` would be more appropriate?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, interesting point and actually mirroring what I was discussing with a colleague. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's hard to give you a good solution without understanding more of the context. But these don't smell like actual constants and more like a policy.

Comment: No, they are constants. I just need a structure to hold some hard coded int's for use in several places. I'm just centralising some settings that are in two places currently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you try with [*nested classes*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) like this:

```
public static class AgeConstants
{
    public class Hotel
    {
      public const int MinHotelAge = 0;
      public const int MaxHotelAge = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Liam yes you are right, we are not actually utilizing partial here, changed it to class only

Comment: These are called *nested classes*. I also recommend against using inline code for things that are not code. In this case italique formatting would be a good choice.