# How to Refer to Excel Ranges without Widespread Hard Coding of Index Numbers or Column Letters

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I am an untrained, amateur programmer. I'm writing some vb.net code that manipulates Excel spreadsheets. To make my code easier to maintain, I do not want to hard code cell references/column indexes all over the place the way the Microsoft (et al) examples show, like this:

```
.Cells(1,1)
.Range("A1")
```

I'd rather create some sort of definition that I can use to do something like this:

```
.Cells(row, ExportedSalesSheet.PURCHASE_ORDER_COLUMN)
```

Then I can change values in one place should the spreadsheets produced by an independent system ever change.

I've tried using a class with public constants (see example above) but that seems to get ugly pretty fast as it seems sometimes the com object needs a string *e.g. "A:A", "A1"* to refer to a column or cell; other times it needs an index number, other times it needs row and column index numbers.

I'd like something that's easy to ready and also makes it easy for me to return an index or letter depending on need. Perhaps something like this?

```
ExportedSalesSheet.columns.purchase_order.index
ExportedSalesSheet.columns.purchase_order.letter
ExportedSalesSheet.cells.header_text.row.index
ExportedSalesSheet.cells.header_text.column.letter
ExportedSalesSheet.cells.header_text.column.index
```

I have no idea how to create such an object or whether the concept follows best practice. Maybe there's a better way.

Any suggestions would be very gratefully received.

Comment: I have heard good things about EPPlus. Give it a google.

Answer (score 0):

This solution involves using 'nested classes' (something I didn't know about until I read this thread, [Building a constant hierarchy structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231006/building-a-constant-hierarchy-structure) (accessed 2020-11-18)

```
Public Class ExportedSalesSheet

    Class Columns

        Class Service
            Public Const Heading As String = "Description"
            Public Const Index As Integer = 5
            Public Const Letter As String = "E"
        End Class

        Class Comments
            Public Const Heading As String = "Comments"
            Public Const Index As Integer = 2
            Public Const Letter As String = "B"
        End Class

        Class Fee
            Public Const Heading As String = "Fee"
            Public Const Index As Integer = 7
            Public Const Letter As String = "G"
        End Class

    End Class

End Class
```

Although not the conventional way that I have always DEFINED_CONSTANTS in the past, this method gives you assistance from IntelliSense and preserves the easy to code, easy to read and easy to update hierarchical structure of the original data. Here's an example

```
Dim serviceDescription As String = vbNullString & _
    .Cells(currentRow, ExportedSalesSheet.Columns.Service.Index).Value
```